# "sudo rosmake" permission denied problem

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to install the rgbdslam package and following the installation instructions here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM

I've svn checked out "rgbdslam" and "hogman_minimal" packaged into my "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks" directory.

When I try to issue the command "rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam" it gives an error mid-way into the installation saying "mkdir: cannot create directory `build': Permission denied". Naturally, I tried adding sudo infront of the command, but then I get the error "sudo: rosmake: command not found".

What is wrong?

Here are the lines from my bashrc file, in case this has to do with some incorrect environment paths:

source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9350/%22sudo-rosmake%22-permission-denied-problem/) by [Shark](https://answers.ros.org/users/264/shark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case someone else stumbles across this question: note that the `/opt/ros` package directories are intended to be shared by all users on that system.

*Modifying their contents is not a good idea.*

As `shark` hinted above, if you need to modify one of the installed packages, check the sources for its stack out of the source repository, placing them *ahead* of the `/opt/ros` stacks in the `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. Then, use `rosmake` normally to build your modified version. That way, tools like `svn diff` or `git diff` make it easy to submit your changes as a patch.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-12-09**:
Oh, sneaky little http://... :-)

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-12-08**:
@Röhling Correct URL: http://answers.ros.org/question/2304/

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-11-27**:
This applies even for a single-user machine. If you have installed ROS via Ubuntu packages, the package manager will not preserve changes you made to /opt/ros, so you will end up like http://http://answers.ros.org/question/2304

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2012-03-30**:
I type rosmake stage and gives the same problem. I haven't changed anything. Just following the instructions

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed the problem. Instead of downloading stacks into a restricted folder, downloaded to my own folder and made sure the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH included this new directory. When I ran the rosmake command, it worked.

Another (hacked) solution I found was changing the read/write/exec permissions on the folders within the /opt/ros/.../rgbdslam folders.

---

Originally posted by [Shark](https://answers.ros.org/users/264/shark/) with karma: 241 on 2011-03-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-09**:
This hack is unpredictable as a new update might overwrite your changes and delete files.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When checking out stacks from SVN you might want to use the rosinstall mechanism. Download rosinstall from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rosinstall/ and follow the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall). I can see that you have already found a solution for your problem, but the rosinstall setup is quite comfortable (also helpful to quickly setting up environment and path).

---

Originally posted by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) with karma: 960 on 2011-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem when I am  installing orocos and i found that  change the owner of the directory (using chown )can solve the problem:

chown -R username:groupname \mydirectory

(i.e.)

chown -R robot:robot /home/robot/ros_workspace

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/mandriva-linux/38322-folder-permissions.html

---

Originally posted by [remlog](https://answers.ros.org/users/3008/remlog/) with karma: 66 on 2012-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1